# How return Class with Collection of G, where G is generic?

Tags: java, generics

How i can return `Class<Collection<G>>`, where G is generic?

```
  public Class<Collection<G>> getType() {
    return (Class<Collection<G>>)Collection.class; // This is wrong
  }
```

Comment: That's actually right. There's no such thing as `Collection<G>.class` in Java because of how generics work.

Comment: You can use super type tokens: http://gafter.blogspot.sk/2006/12/super-type-tokens.html - they might be useful in your use case. (When you only need a reference to the generic type signature, not an honest-to-goodness reified `Class` because those do not indeed exist.)

Comment: Well i do not get it. `Class<Collection<G>>` makes no sense as G is how ever lost

Comment: There is no way to return `G` as this type is lost at runtime due to type erasure.

Comment: @Jatin `Class<Collection<G>>` might be useful at compile time if you need to use its type to convince some generic factory method that takes a `Class<T>` token that it should return a `Collection<G>`. I've seen it before in spring `ConverterFactory`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your cast doesn't work due to `Collection.class` being a class of raw `Collection` (`Class<Collection>`) which is not a supertype of `Class<Collection<G>>`. One choice to get the cast to work is to upcast to `Class<?>` and then downcast to `Class<Collection<G>>`. This works because you can always upcast to a supertype and then the downcast is an unchecked cast which in this case will never throw an exception at runtime.

For the generic part you will need a generic method which declares a generic type parameter `G`.

```
@SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
public <G> Class<Collection<G>> getType() {
    return (Class<Collection<G>>)(Class<?>)Collection.class;
}
```

Comment: or, to avoid raw types, use `Class<?>` instead of `Class`